# CPU Utilization of Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

My Nifi processor consumes 100% of the CPU.Can I manually configure CPU utilization of Apache Nifi in any of the configuration files namely nifi.properties or bootstrap.conf?

Comment: You could change thread count for a processor or for the whole nifi. And you can set different schedule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration options to adjust this, but you can adjust processors configuration to avoid problems, but with the information you provided, it's difficult to know what's going on in your NiFi.

First of all you must know if make sense that this processor consumes 100% CPU, most of this cases can be avoided configuring the processor scheduling properly.

[image]

As you can see, Run Schedule, Run Duration and Concurrent Tasks should be carefully adjusted to get the best from our NiFi.